# Winforms DataRepeater Catch Data Changed

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, custom-controls

[image: DataRepeater Control]

I have a WinForm with a [Visual Basic Power Packs - DataRepeater control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488279.aspx) and on this control I have a check box that is Data Bound to a Boolean Field in my Database.  The Database is just XML with XSD.

```
Me.AutoDownloadCheckBox.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("CheckState", Me.TVSeriesBindingSource, "AutoDownload", True))
```

I tried to catch the click event of the check box and it throws the event when the check box is checked.  But the changes are not saved.

```
Imports TvSeriesData
Imports System.IO

Public Class Repeater  

    Private LocalDS As New TVSeriesDB 

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        Dim TempFile As FileInfo
        TempFile = New FileInfo(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\" & "TvLinks" & "\TVSeriesDB.xml")
        If TempFile.Exists Then
            LocalDS.ReadXml(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\" & "TvLinks" & "\TVSeriesDB.xml")
        End If

        DataRepeater1.DataSource = LocalDS.TVSeries

    End Sub        

    Private Sub AutoDownloadCheckBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AutoDownloadCheckBox.Click
        If LocalDS.HasChanges() Then LocalDS.AcceptChanges()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am reading the Database from XML when you AcceptChanges all it does is updates in memory but not the actual XML file.

```
LocalDS.WriteXml(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\" & "TvLinks" & "\TVSeriesDB.xml")
```

So I needed to write back to the XML file to actually save the changes made in memory.  This can be a time consuming process if the Database is big so use a Async function to save.